# javascript enable disabled button

Tags: javascript

When event A happens I disable a button:

```
if (document.getElementById('detail_n').checked) {
  chkxp.disabled = true; }
```

But if event B happens I want to re-enable the button:

```
if (document.getElementById('detail_y').checked) {
  chkxp.disabled = false; }
```

That did not re-enable the button.  I tried:

```
chkxp.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

That did not work either.

I HAVE LOOKED AT THE OTHER PAGES WHICH PRESENT SOLUTIONS, AND THEY ARE EXACTLY WHAT I ALREADY HAVE, WHICH IS NOT WORKING FOR ME.  THAT IS WHY I AM ASKING AGAIN.

The only thing that worked is to re-submit the page.  That would be a huge pain for the user, since there is a lot of stuff to fill into that form.

I'm in firefox.  Can anyone give me a Javascript solution that does work?

Comment: I had looked at that, but found nothing there that worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine with setting disabled to true and then removing the disabled attribute in order to re-enable the buttton. checkout MDN nd snippet below: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn2.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (btn.disabled === true) {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    console.log('Target is enabled');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Target is disabled');
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Target</button>
  <button id="btn2">Click here !</button>
</body>
</html>
```

### **UPDATE**

Snippet for radio buttons. 
if my snippet doesn't work on your browser, please check your browser settings.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');

btn2.addEventListener('change',function () {
  if (btn2.checked === true) {
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
});

btn3.addEventListener('change',function () {
  if (btn3.checked === true) {
    btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="radio" id="btn"><label for="btn">Target</label>
  <input type="radio" name="x" id="btn2"><label for="btn2">Disable target</label>
  <input type="radio" name="x" id="btn3"><label for="btn3">Enable target</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe something else in your code mess things up? can you please post it? Does the snippet in my answer works for you?

Comment: This is not working.  I have a radio button, not a regular button.  Otherwise it seems the same.  I included the relevant code in my question.  What are you looking for?  Do you want the HTML?

Comment: Does your if statements are inside event listener? without listening to events you can't response to user actions. I edit my answer with a snippet for radio buttons, please check it out.

Comment: I'musing an onchange inside the radio button.  If the user picks another button, that also has  an onchange, so the program will catch it.  I also change the color with the disable; and change it back when I set the disable to false.  The color changes are working.  Here is the calling code:      <input type  = "radio" 
                class = "moxradio round"                
                name  = "#colu#subh"
                id    = "subh_h_#jsort#"
                onchange = "rephidcol('#jsort#')"  
                value = "h">hidden

Comment: Hi Betty, you should **check your "rephidcol" function**. Also **be sure to remove cache from browser before you try to check your updated code**. Recommendation : In most cases you should use **Event Listeners** over inline event handlers (more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/8737670).

Comment: I removed the javascript caching long ago.  the rephidcol function seems to be working except for not re-enabling the disabled buttons.  I know the event listener is recommended, but for now I'm using the more easily coded inline handler.

Comment: Well, something must be faulty with your code. The way I mentioned is the right way to do it. I can try to help you if you post your full js & html.

Comment: I have hundreds of lines of HTML.  Where would I post all that?

Comment: Just post the relevant html

Comment: Well, I've worked around it by setting visibility to hidden.  As I said, there are hundreds of lines of html, and I don't want to try to find a place to put them.